# Json Parameters always empty

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to build an OData endpoint using the Entity Framework. Routing is working fine.

I have a post method in my controller to which post requests get routed correctly, however it receives null parameters even though I am passing parameters (Using Fiddler 4).

My controller method is :

```
  [HttpPost,EnableQuery]
  public IHttpActionResult GetConfig_Post(ODataQueryOptions<GetConfig_Result> options, ODataActionParameters parameter)
        {  ...  }
```

The ODataActionParameters parameter is always empty.

The routing code is:

```
   public override string SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
        {
            if (odataPath != null && odataPath.PathTemplate == "~/entityset/action")
            {
                var segment = odataPath.Segments.First() as EntitySetPathSegment;
                string typeName = segment.EntitySetName;
                if (controllerContext != null && (segment != null && controllerContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post))
                {
                    if (typeName == "Config")
                    {
                        return "GetConfig_Post";
                    }
                }
            }
```

I can't find a reason why the below POST request is handled with null parameters. [Request as in Fiddler, HTTP version set to 1.1]

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:52673
Content-Length: 36

Data:
{"id":"21"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WebAPI and passing data in request body I believe you have to use `[FromBody]` parameter attribute.

What is more, I believe you can use only one parameter in controller's POST action.

Comment: frombody is relevant where you're submiting the form I think.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh - not true, it is widely used when binding data from Ajax POST request also. It is still HTTP POST.

Comment: I haven't used this attribute in a while , while building WebApi and I used $.ajax. works perfectly.

Comment: @Kamo  [FromBody] is unnecessary because it's by default.

Comment: @Novak007, Would you please share us your model class and the model build procedure? Please make sure the Edm Action defined correctly in the model. [Here](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataActionsSample) is sample that you can refer to.